# "Unexpected T_STRING"?

Tags: php, parsing

```
echo "Info: <input type=\"text\" name=\"titel\"> value=\" . $row['titel'] . "\">" . "<br />";
```

Why is it showing:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
>   in /home/lokachan/public_html/andravisaform.php on line 24

Comment: Use a php IDE to save this types of headaches in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would save you typing

```
$input = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\"><br \/>";

echo sprintf ( $input, "title1",$row ['titel'] );
echo sprintf ( $input, "title2",$row ['tite2'] );
```

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
echo "Info: <input type=\"text\" name=\"titel\"> value=\"" . $row['titel'] . "\">" . "<br />";
```

You're missing a `"` after a `\"`.

I would prefer to write it as:

```
echo 'Info: <input type="text" name="titel"> value="' . $row['titel'] . '"><br />';
```

Now you don't need so many escapes.

Comment: [Better yet](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), `<p>Info: <input type="text" name="titel" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['titel']); ?>"><br />...`
`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a quote

```
echo "Info: <input type=\"text\" name=\"titel\"> value=\"" . $row['titel'] . "\">" . "<br />";
```